# Upsize Access Backend To SQL Server - Query Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm completely new to the SQL Server portion of databases.  I've created a split Access database that functions well.

As a test I upsized the tables to SQL server.  For the most part everything went smoothly; however, two of my queries are no longer working.  They are both fairly complex union queries.  I believe the union is the culprit to my issues.

With the first one I have two queries using union all.  They work individually, but when I use the union query I receive the error "object invalid or no longer set".

With the second one I have 3 queries with union all.  These are simpler than the first case.  This time I receive the error "The expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated."

Is there something specific about union queries with tables on SQL server?  Any help or advice is appreciated.

```
SELECT scrap.coilnum, Sum(scrap.lnff) AS sumoflnff, scrap.code, scrap.location
FROM scrap
WHERE scrap.day>=[Forms]![coilparameters]![Text0] And scrap.day<=[Forms]![coilparameters]![Text2] and scrap.productionline=[Forms]![coilparameters]![combo4] and scrap.coilnum<>0
GROUP BY scrap.coilnum, scrap.code, scrap.location;
union all
SELECT sawscrap.tcoilnum, Sum(sawscrap.length) AS sumoflnff, sawscrap.code, sawscrap.location
FROM sawscrap
WHERE sawscrap.day>=[Forms]![coilparameters]![text0] And sawscrap.day<=[Forms]![coilparameters]![text2] and sawscrap.productionline=[Forms]![coilparameters]![combo4] and sawscrap.tcoilnum is not null and sawscrap.tcoilnum<>0
GROUP BY sawscrap.tcoilnum, sawscrap.code, sawscrap.location;
UNION ALL
SELECT sawscrap.bcoilnum, Sum(sawscrap.length) AS sumoflnff, sawScrap.code, sawscrap.location
FROM sawscrap
WHERE sawscrap.day>=[Forms]![coilparameters]![text0] And sawscrap.day<=[Forms]![coilparameters]![text2] and sawscrap.productionline=[Forms]![coilparameters]![combo4] and sawscrap.bcoilnum is not null and sawscrap.bcoilnum<>0
GROUP BY sawscrap.bcoilnum, sawscrap.code, sawscrap.location;
```

There is the second one.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL that gives the error?  Union and Union All in SQL Server are not special. pretty simple.

Comment: Everything is still in Access except for the tables themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual cause of these sorts of errors in Access `UNION` queries is a data type mismatch between each `SELECT` column and the column(s) in the same position in the other `SELECT` statement(s).

In your case, are the datatypes of `scrap.coilnum`, `sawscrap.tcoilnum` and `sawscrap.bcoilnum` the same? What about the other columns?  If they are not, you may need to use a conversion function (e.g. `CStr` or `CLng`) to make them all the same type.

Have a look at [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-HA010206109.aspx) for more information.

Comment: They are the same.  The exact same union query works fine while the tables are in an Access back end.  When upsized to SQL Server the errors show up.

Comment: You were on the right path.  The issue wasn't that the three coil numbers had different field types, it's that it was a different data type than a parameter I was using.  Thanks for the help!